# Listening for Flash Events using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I am trying to listen to a an event that is fired by a game when it is fully loaded.

```
window.addEventListener('gameReady', function(event) {
            console.log(event.data);
```

});

I know that the gameReady is fired when it is ready to play.  IS the above code correct and is there anyway way I can view NON CLICK/INTERFACE events in the Chrome console?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ExternalInterface to call javascript functions.

```
if (ExternalInterface.available)
{
    ExternalInterface.call('console.log', event.data);
}
```

Just remember that console.log might not be able to process flash objects.

Answer (score 0):

You must listen to the event on the flash object.

[More info here.](http://help.adobe.com/fr_FR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)